# Return a mapped object using Slick

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

How can I return a mapped object using Slick?  Using the following code my query returns List[(Int, String)] and not a List[Task] like I want it to.  Is this not possible using Slick or am I thinking about Slick the wrong way is it not an ORM? I'm trying to return a query and use it in a view template using the Play2 framework.  I'd like to end up accessing the objects like task.id task.label etc...  Thanks.

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db._
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

case class Task(id: Int, label: String)

object Task extends Table[(Int, String)]("TASKS") {

  lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def label = column[String]("LABEL")

  def * = id ~ label

  def all() : List[Task] = database.withSession { implicit db: Session =>
    Query(Task).list
  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that using a singleton object for the Table can lead to problems in Slick 1.x if it is placed in a static location (a package or another singleton object). To be safe either use classes and vals or place the singleton objects in classes/traits as members.

Comment: @cvogt I've not heard this before and most of the examples I've seen use singletons. Can you provide a link to more information on why this should be avoided please?

Comment: The corresponding Scala bug report https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you defined your table.  Try changing your table definition to:

```
case class Task(id: Int, label: String)
object Task extends Table[Task]("TASKS") {
  lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def label = column[String]("LABEL")
  def * = id ~ label <> (Task.apply _, Task.unapply _)
  def all() : List[Task] = database.withSession { implicit db: Session =>
    Query(Task).list
  }
}
```

The difference is that the type param I am passing to the `Table` is `Task` instead of `(Int, String)`.  This should fix your issue.

Comment: I get the same error:

type mismatch; found : List[(Int, String)] required: List[models.Task]

Comment: @nek4life, I updated with what I now believe to be the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you!  That was the issue.

I was using the documentation [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/gettingstarted.html) where they show the type params matching the columns.  I thought I had to specify my table that way.  Any more information about the type param and what it does would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again!